# Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException Failed to create remote render context

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

App crashes with internal inconsistency exception at `initWithFrame` method on `UIWindow`

Crash log points to line:

`self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];`

So far crash reported on iPhone with iOS 9.

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x180bd5900 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x180243f80 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x180bd57d0 +[NSException raise:format:]
3  Foundation                     0x18154899c -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:]
4  UIKit                          0x185bbaffc -[UIWindow _createContextAttached:]
5  UIKit                          0x185bb926c -[UIWindow _commonInitAttachedWindow:debugName:scene:]
6  UIKit                          0x185bb95f4 -[UIWindow _initWithFrame:debugName:scene:attached:]
7  JioPlay                        0x10010e610 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (AppDelegate.m:475)
8  UIKit                          0x18593d704 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:]
9  UIKit                          0x185b6c130 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:]
10 UIKit                          0x185b704b8 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:]
11 UIKit                          0x185b6d5c0 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:]
12 FrontBoardServices             0x18218b790 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext]
13 FrontBoardServices             0x18218bb10 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource]
14 CoreFoundation                 0x180b8cefc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
15 CoreFoundation                 0x180b8c990 __CFRunLoopDoSources0
16 CoreFoundation                 0x180b8a690 __CFRunLoopRun
17 CoreFoundation                 0x180ab9680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
18 UIKit                          0x185936580 -[UIApplication _run]
19 UIKit                          0x185930d90 UIApplicationMain
20 JioPlay                        0x1001bcf28 main (main.m:26)
21 libdyld.dylib                  0x18065a8b8 start
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether LR/PC register address belongs to your app in binary images. if not, I recommend you radar your bug to Apple.
If you fixed this bug, you can share your solution to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42691809/app-crashed-due-to-nsinternalinconsistencyexceptionsigabrt-failed-to-create/42692266).

Comment: The link appears to have died.